# ui slider to animate and update divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, uislider

i am trying to get a timeline graph to work but am struggling, i dont know how to crowbar the animation into the code and have the slider handle play left to right onload and update the divs at the same time, any ideas very welcome :)

[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/swinky/WXfkK/246/)

JS

```
$('#slider').slider({
    value: 0,
    min: 1,
    max: 100,
    slide: handleSliderChange
});

function handleSliderChange(event, slider) {
    $('#vardiv').css('height', 150 - slider.value / 100 * 50);
    $('#vardiv1').css('height', slider.value / 100 * 90);
    $('#vardiv2').css('height', slider.value / 100 * 20);
    $('#vardiv3').css('height', 100 - slider.value / 100 * 40);
    $('#vardiv4').css('height', slider.value / 100 * 70);


}
```

HTML

```
<h1>Health Benefits</h1>

<div id="slider"></div>
<div id="container">
    <div id="vardiv"></div>
    <div id="vardiv1"></div>
    <div id="vardiv2"></div>
    <div id="vardiv3"></div>
    <div id="vardiv4"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took time, but got it! :)

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/yvt4Z/5/)

### JS:

```
$("#slider").slider({
    value: 0,
    max: 100,
    min: 100
});

function handleSliderChange(event, slider) {
    $('#vardiv').css('height', 150 - slider.value / 100 * 50);
    $('#vardiv1').css('height', slider.value / 100 * 90);
    $('#vardiv2').css('height', slider.value / 100 * 20);
    $('#vardiv3').css('height', 100 - slider.value / 100 * 40);
    $('#vardiv4').css('height', slider.value / 100 * 70);
}

var val = 0,
    bool = true; // indicates whether to increase value (true) or decrease (false)

// Replicates the slider parameter in the `handleSliderChange` function
var obj = {
    value: val,
    max: 100,
    min: 0
};

// Every second
setInterval(function () {

    // Call the default function
    $("#slider").slider(obj);

    // Perform the bool checks
    if(bool !== null){
        if (bool)
            val += 10;
        else
            val -= 10;
    }

    // Boundary check: if crossed boundary, reverse irection (bool)
    if(bool !== null && val === 100){
        var answer = confirm("Continue animating?");
        bool = answer ? false : null;
    }else if (bool !== null && (val >= 100 || val <= 0)){
        bool = !bool;
    }

    if(bool !== null){
        obj.value = val;
        // Event is unused hence no harm in leaving undefined
        handleSliderChange(undefined, obj);
    }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Wow that was fast and almost perfect thank you. if possible i would need it to stop at the end and allow the user to manipulate the handle to look back on the graph again